# Sending a FormData's object with $http and strange RequestPayload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

My goal is send a base64 string, that represents a cropped image. 
I have a function in my controller (AngularJS):

```
$scope.submit = function()
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', $scope.croppedImage);
  $http({
    url: '/',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': undefined
    },
    data: formData
  })
  .then(function(){
     console.log('success');
  }, function(){
     console.log('error');
  })
;
```

and when I run the function in Network Tab of DevTools, it shows me that:

> Request Payload
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundary1mt4B5vN2A0hO5yo Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
>
> someValue(Base64 string)
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundary1mt4B5vN2A0hO5yo--

the new field appears like a value of name and the "someValue"

Comment: That is normal. I'm guessing you want to upload the image data like you would a file. If so then convert the base64 string to a blob and add that instead to the formdata object.

Comment: In the server I have a Symfony's Form with a bundle "VichUploaderBundle", I don´t know  if this will work.